# вхождение точки в полигон

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Через ROM отрисовываю полигоны.На клиенте, с помощью геокодирования получаю массив точек. Задача: выделить те точки, которые попали в полигоны. Можно ли как то на клиенте получит координаты отрисованных полигонов для последующей проверки на вхождения с помощью GeoQuery или .contains? Или на сервере можно как то проверить на вхождения? Серверная часть на NODE JS.

Answer (score 1):

Решилось установкой на сервер модуля npm "robust-point-in-polygon". Модуль имеет 3 состояния:
-1 - точка входит в полигон,
0 - точка находится на границе или вершине полигона,
1 - точка не входит а полигон.